# How does the 'Ternary Operator' i.e. the 'conditional operator' work with the 'echo' statement since the 'echo' statement doesn't return any value?

Tags: php, echo, return-value, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I'm using **PHP 7.3.6** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system**.

I've installed the latest version of **XAMPP** installer on my laptop which has installed the **Apache/2.4.39 (Win64)** and **PHP 7.3.6**

Today, I come across following code example from the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#refsect1-function.echo-examples) :

```
<?php
  echo $some_var ? 'true': 'false'; // changing the statement around
?>
```

As per my knowledge and according to the following text from [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) :

> The expression *(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)* evaluates to expr2 if expr1
>   evaluates to **TRUE**, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to **FALSE**.

It's also a well-known fact that `echo` statement in PHP doesn't return any value.

So, in the code example mentioned above also `echo` statement must not be returning any value.

So, my question is as the `echo` statement never returns any value how does the ternary operator comes to know that `expr1(i.e. the statement echo $some_var)` has been evaluated to true or false and accordingly prints the output as `true` or `false`?

Comment: @treyBake : I know that `echo` isn't a built-in function in PHP, it's a language construct. My doubt is functionality of the ternary operator solely depends on the value of **expr1**. Then, how it's been determined with the `echo` statement that whether the **expr1** evaluates to `true` or `false` as echo never returns any value?

Comment: It's not `echo` being evaluated by the ternary expression. It's the `$some_var`. It's testing whether that is `true` or `false` and returning the string `'True'` or the string `'False'` which is only then echo'd by `echo`.

Comment: you're not using the echo to return a value, you're using echo in conjunction with a ternary statement to minimise lines. The echo is irrelevant, it could be an include, a var_dump, a print_r - it's what's inside the ternary that's relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're reading the logic incorrectly. Which is why I like brackets for my ternary statements. Your ternary is the same as:

```
if ($some_var) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

the echo isn't being used in the conditional. If we change the ternary to this, things are clearer:

```
echo ($some_var ? 'true' : 'false');
```

this can be seen as `echo (if ($some_var) {true} else {false})` (from a logic point of view at least)

So it's not the echo that's being tested, it's the bit before the `?` - that's the if statement conditional, not the `echo`

Answer (score 3):

Echo is kind of a strange player in the PHP game. When it is executed, it is actually wrapping your statement in parenthesis to be more like a function.

So

```php
<?php

$something = true;

// this
echo $something ? 'is true' : 'is false';

// becomes 
echo($something ? 'is true' : 'is false');
```

where the ternary expression evaluates to 'is true' and that is "echoed".